# Function to see if there is a break in circuit (2D Array)

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a function that lets me see if there is a break in a circuit which I've stored in a 2D Array by returning either true or false. For simplicity sake i have modeled the circuit using 1's and 0's. With 1's being components and 0's being spaces. I have tried messing with recursive functions however to no avail and am pretty much stuck at this point.

For example:

```
1 1 1

1 0 1

1 1 1
```

I would like this to return true as all the 1's are connected in series. This 2D array would be visualized [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXP6z.png).

```
1 1 1

0 0 1

1 1 1
```

I would like this to return false as there is a break in the circuit as 
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6ZpH.png).

Any solutions or guidance would be much appreciated!

My current code is shown below. It returns incomplete when I used the completeCircuit as an input however returns complete when I have the incompleteCircuit as an input.

```
    public class TraversalTest
    {
    boolean complete = false;
    int runs = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TraversalTest traversal = new TraversalTest();
    }

    public TraversalTest()
    {
        Cell[][] completeCircuit =
            {
                { new Cell( 0,  0,  1), new Cell(   1,  0,  1), new Cell(   2,  0,  1) }, 
                { new Cell( 0,  1,  1), new Cell(   1,  1,  0), new Cell(   2,  1,  1) },
                { new Cell( 0,  2,  1), new Cell(   1,  2,  1), new Cell(   2,  2,  1) }
            };

        Cell[][] incompleteCircuit =
            {
                { new Cell( 0,  0,  1), new Cell(   1,  0,  1), new Cell(   2,  0,  1) }, 
                { new Cell( 0,  1,  0), new Cell(   1,  1,  0), new Cell(   2,  1,  1) },
                { new Cell( 0,  2,  1), new Cell(   1,  2,  1), new Cell(   2,  2,  1) }
            };

        completeCircuit[1][0].connected = true;
        int cellsLeft = (numOfPositiveCells(completeCircuit));

        checkComplete(completeCircuit, completeCircuit[1][0], cellsLeft);


        incompleteCircuit[1][0].connected = true;
        int cellsLeft1 = (numOfPositiveCells(incompleteCircuit));

        checkComplete(incompleteCircuit, incompleteCircuit[1][0], cellsLeft1);
    }

    void checkComplete(Cell[][] circuit, Cell currentCell, int cellsLeft)
    {
        currentCell.connected = true;

        if(cellsLeft > 0)
        {
            if(currentCell.x != 0 && circuit[currentCell.x-1][currentCell.y].value == 1 && 
                    circuit[currentCell.x-1][currentCell.y].connected == false)
            {
                cellsLeft--;
                checkComplete(circuit, circuit[currentCell.x-1][currentCell.y], cellsLeft);
            }
            else if(currentCell.x != 2 &&circuit[currentCell.x+1][currentCell.y].value == 1 && 
                    circuit[currentCell.x+1][currentCell.y].connected == false)
            {
                cellsLeft--;
                checkComplete(circuit, circuit[currentCell.x+1][currentCell.y], cellsLeft);
            }
            else if(currentCell.y != 0 && circuit[currentCell.x][currentCell.y-1].value == 1 && 
                    circuit[currentCell.x][currentCell.y-1].connected == false)
            {
                cellsLeft--;
                checkComplete(circuit, circuit[currentCell.x][currentCell.y-1], cellsLeft);
            }
            else if(currentCell.y != 2 && circuit[currentCell.x][currentCell.y+1].value == 1 && 
                    circuit[currentCell.x][currentCell.y+1].connected == false)
            {
                cellsLeft--;
                checkComplete(circuit, circuit[currentCell.x][currentCell.y+1], cellsLeft);
            }
            else
            {
                complete = false;
                System.out.println("Incomplete");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            complete = true;
            System.out.println("Complete");
        }
    }

    int numOfPositiveCells(Cell[][] circuit)
    {
        int num = 0;
        for(int x=0; x < 3; x++)
            for(int y=0; y < 3; y++)
                if(circuit[x][y].value == 1)
                    num++;
        return num;
    }
}

class Cell
{
    public boolean connected;
    public int value;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Cell(int x, int y, int value)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: add all 1 and 0s in each sub array and divide by its length(i.e 3). if it gives you 1 one then true else false

Comment: Would this also be a closed circuit 2d array? First row (left-to-right): 0, 1, 1. Second row: 1, 0, 1. Third row: 0, 1, 0

Comment: Well if you are stuck then post the code you have so far and explain what your issue is with the code.

Comment: Added a link to my code, I hope it helps :)

Comment: I've made a little program to emulate what I was initially trying to do and have edited the post accordingly, thank you.

Comment: Thanks! But please include code in your question, do not link to external websites.

Comment: you probably just need to check that each 1 is connected to 2 and only 2 other 1s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think checking that every cell has 2 connections should work for your use cases as we only look for series connections.

You just need to go through your array and make sure that all live cells have 2 and only 2 live cells connected to it

I'd suggest you make a dedicated class, this way you don't have to keep passing the circuit around in all the methods:

```
class CircuitChecker {
    private final Cell[][] circuit;
    private final int nbRows, nbCols;

    public CircuitChecker(Cell[][] circuit) {
        this.circuit = circuit;
        this.nbRows = circuit.length;
        this.nbCols = circuit[0].length;
    }

    public boolean isCircuitComplete() {
        boolean isComplete = true;
        for(int col = 0; col<nbCols; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < nbRows; row++) {
                if(cellIsLive(col, row) && !cellHas2LiveConnections(col, row)) {
                    isComplete = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return isComplete;
    }

    private boolean cellIsLive(int col, int row) {
        return circuit[row][col].value == 1;
    }

    private boolean cellHas2LiveConnections(int col, int row) {
        Cell left = col > 0 ? circuit[col-1][row] : null;
        Cell right = col < nbCols-1 ? circuit[col+1][row] : null;
        Cell up = row > 0 ? circuit[col][row-1] : null;
        Cell down = row < nbRows-1 ? circuit[col][row+1] : null;

        int nbConnections = Stream.of(left, right, up, down)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .mapToInt(c -> c.value)
                .sum();
        return nbConnections == 2;
    }
}
```

you call it this way:

```
new CircuitChecker(completeCircuit).isCircuitComplete();
new CircuitChecker(incompleteCircuit).isCircuitComplete();
```

One more thing, the fields in your class `Cell` should be private (and even maybe final) and you should access them via getters.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works perfectly. I've also changed what you recommended at the bottom of your answer. I really appreciate the help! :)